# What is the default frequency if it is not explicitly specified in a pipeline activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

If we don't explicitly define 'frequency' in a pipeline activity, what is the default? I have noticed that 'hour' seems to be the default but I just want to make sure. My activity type is HDInsightHive , assuming that this default does not change across different activity types. I am using ADF v1.

Comment: Are you using v1 or v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you are using v1. Then according to [this doc](http://Currently,%20output%20dataset%20drives%20the%20schedule.%20In%20other%20words,%20the%20schedule%20specified%20for%20the%20output%20dataset%20is%20used%20to%20run%20an%20activity%20at%20runtime.%20Therefore,%20you%20must%20create%20an%20output%20dataset%20even%20if%20the%20activity%20does%20not%20produce%20any%20output.%20If%20the%20activity%20doesn't%20take%20any%20input,%20you%20can%20skip%20creating%20the%20input%20dataset.):

**Currently, output dataset drives the schedule.** In other words, the schedule specified for the output dataset is used to run an activity at runtime. Therefore, you must create an output dataset even if the activity does not produce any output. If the activity doesn't take any input, you can skip creating the input dataset.

And scheduler is a required property for dataset.

The scheduler property for an activity is optional. If you do specify this property, it must match the cadence you specify in the definition of output dataset for the activity. Currently, output dataset is what drives the schedule. Therefore, you must create an output dataset even if the activity does not produce any output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ADFV2 then we have triggers in place to schedule the pipeline. When we come to the point of scheduling a trigger which determines when to execute the pipeline.

Coming to frequency - the supported values include "minute", "hour", "day", "week", and "month" and this is a required property which has to be defined while creation.

When you create any trigger through Data Factory UI - you would be presented with this screen -

[image]

As you could see the recurrence(frequency) has been defaulted to - "Every Minute".